# Webiste scraping facing issue with " load button"

Tags: web-scraping, scrape

I am unable to scrape all the urls of the file newsletter. I only scrape first page urls. this is link to the website.
https://news.matdesousa.com/

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://news.matdesousa.com/"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'}

## Make a request to the URL to get the HTML content

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

## Find inner divs within the specified class

inner_divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='group h-full overflow-hidden transition-all shadow-none hover:shadow-none rounded-lg')

## Extract links from each inner div

for inner_div in inner_divs:
link = inner_div.find('a')['href']
print(link)

Comment: you have to find the "load more" button and execute a click then do that till load more is not there then do you link extracting

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your title should be a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

For this specific question you will need to have control over the browser. Selenium or puppeteer are good for automating tasks a human would do in the browser, such as moving your mouse or clicking/scrolling things inside of the browser. You will need to click the Load More button. I have found it by using something called "xpath" you should use this as it is more reliable when scraping. This code below should work for your implementation.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import time

# Setup Selenium WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path/to/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://news.matdesousa.com/")
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'
}



try:
    driver.get("https://news.matdesousa.com/")
    
    while True:
        # Find the "Load More" button by its text
        load_more_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(., 'Load More')]"))
        )
        load_more_button.click()

        # Waiting for the page to load, adjust the time as needed
        time.sleep(5)

except Exception as e:
    print("No more 'Load More' button or error occurred:", e)

# Now that all content is loaded, use BeautifulSoup to parse it
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

# Find inner divs within the specified class, update the class name as needed
inner_divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='group h-full overflow-hidden transition-all shadow-none hover:shadow-none rounded-lg')

# Extract links from each inner div
for inner_div in inner_divs:
    link = inner_div.find('a')['href']
    print(link)

driver.quit()
```